# Is there a Java Agent available that remove final modifier on classes and methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, javaagents

I am looking for a ready to use Java-Agent, that removes all `final` modifiers from classes and methods. I used google but didn't find anything useful. Also i don't want to implement one, because i think it is very difficult even with javassist or ASM!?

What is the motivation?
My quick idea is to overcome the limitations of mocking final classes/methods without introducing addional libraries or reducing the design quality of the code under test.

I want to mock final classes and/or final method's but i don't want to:

- ...remove `final` form classes and method for design reasons
- ...introduce interfaces for classes with exact one implementation
- ...use something like PowerMock

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+f?

Comment: What will be the difference between PowerMock and what you are looking for?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I don't want an additional API parallel to Mockito's, also i want to use Parameter-Tests that require there own Runner

Comment: You can use powermock-mockito binding. It cooperates quite well

Comment: Sure, but you still can't assign 2 different test-runner to one class.